# Problema con el teclado del celular android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-softkeyboard

*Tengo un problema que cuando ejecuto mi aplicación en Android* lo que pasa es que tengo unos botones en la parte inferior de la pantalla y al presionar un EditText aparece el teclado **y oculta mis botones, quiero saber como hacer para que el botón suba al nivel del teclado y de esta manera no se oculte**

Comment: Hey Luis Meneses, bienvenido!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a tu pregunta para que pueda ser bien recibida por la comunidad y obtengas buenas respuestas, te sugiero leer [ask], saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu layout coloca todo el contenido (el `EditText` y los `botones`) dentro de un `ScrollView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            ... />

        <Button>
            ... />

            ...     

    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

La actividad que contiene el boton o botones en el android manifest añade el siguiente atributo:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

El resultado sería:

```
<activity 
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
>
```

En el xml de la actividad que contiene los botones, añade este atributo en el layout que contiene el boton:

```
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Si es un solo layout que contiene todos los demás botones o textviews se lo pones a ese, si el botón este dentro de un layout X que a su vez esta dentro de otro layout Y que sería el global, el atributo irá en el layout x , es decir pónselo al layout en concreto donde se encuentran los botones.

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"  provoca que no se muestre el teclado.

Comment: prueba a poner android:fitsSystemWindows="true" en el layout padre de la actividad y me dices

Comment: si funciono muchas Gracias!!!

Comment: si funciono muchas Gracias!!!

Comment: Genial, de nada, te sugiero entonces que des la respuesta por aceptada haciendo click en el tick que aparece al lado del contador de positivos de mi respuesta, asi otros que tengan el mismo problema veran la respuesta como correcta y la podran usar tambien, muy importante.